# Can't insert records with null values

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

`insert into [Table2] ([a], [b]) select [a], [b] from Table1`

I can't add records if either a or b has null value; otherwise, the code is fine. I did not knowingly define any columns in any table as NOT NULL (columns allow null values by default, yes?).

Table2 has 12 fields and it apparently accepts nulls, as I have successfully inserted into it dozens of records with just two fields (a & b) that have actual values, using the statement above. Only problem is, again, it doesn't add records if either a or b has null value. There are no error messages. I'm working in VB.Net, if that's any help.

Edit: working with MS Access.

Comment: What is your database platform? Can you show the table structure of both?

Comment: What happens if you execute this statement? Do you get errors or are the records simply not inserted?

Comment: @Thorsten It inserts all records from Table1, except if a or b is null. There are no errors.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Was an accident, didn't even notice. I wanted to add the ms-access tag.. But someone was faster then me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't missed to create the table columns with allow null. Check your database where if you have create the columns with "not null" Property.